# Relacionamento ternário de entidades em um esquema relacional seria contra-normativo, e como fazer esse mapeamento em entity framework 6?

Tags: banco-de-dados, asp.net, entity-framework-6, normalização

Tendo como exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podemos abstrair a relação de diversas formas, uma delas seria colocando relação de N p/ N entre projeto e habilidades necessárias, enquanto outra pra empregado e habilidades possuintes, assim como uma pra empregado e projeto em que está alocado. Essa seria a forma correta de realizar essa relação ou uma ternária realmente é a mais apropriada?

Pergunto isso pois estou mexendo com esse tipo de relação em um sistema legado que estou tendo que migrar, aproveito pra perguntar, como faço o mapeamento de uma relação ternária com Entity Framework 6?

Tentei realizar o mapeamento dessa forma, em código de exemplo:

```
             this.HasMany(e => e.Skill)
                 .WithMany(s => s.Employees)
                 .Map(eps =>
                     {
                         eps.MapLeftKey("ID_EMP");
                         eps.MapRightKey("ID_SKILL");
                         eps.ToTable("EMP_SKILL_PROJ");
                     });

             this.HasMany(e => e.Projects)
                 .WithMany(p => p.Emplyees)
                 .Map(eps =>
                     {
                         eps.MapLeftKey("ID_EMP");
                         eps.MapRightKey("ID_PROJECT");
                         eps.ToTable("EMP_SKILL_PROJ");
                     });
```

Repeti esse mapeamento em todas as três classes, da forma que foi necessária de acordo com o contexto de cada.
Mas obviamente obtive a seguinte exceção:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   ProjectSkill: Name: The EntitySet 'ProjectSkill'
>   with table 'EMP_SKILL_PROJ' was already defined. Each EntitySet must
>   refer to a unique schema and table.
>
> ProjectEmployee: Name: The EntitySet 'ProjectEmployee' with
>   table 'EMP_SKILL_PROJ' was already defined. Each EntitySet
>   must refer to a unique schema and table.

Comment: Nesse caso precisa montar a relação e a exposição em um entidade intermediária

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo para que isso funcione é criar uma entidade intermediária explicita e fazer as operações de atualizações nessa entidade intermediária, *exemplo*:

***Modelos:***

```
public partial class Employee
{
  public Employee()
  {
     EmployeeSkillProject = new HashSet<EmployeeSkillProject>();
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<EmployeeSkillProject> EmployeeSkillProject { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Project
{
  public Project()
  {
     EmployeeSkillProject = new HashSet<EmployeeSkillProject>();
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<EmployeeSkillProject> EmployeeSkillProject { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Skill
{
  public Skill()
  {
     EmployeeSkillProject = new HashSet<EmployeeSkillProject>();
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<EmployeeSkillProject> EmployeeSkillProject { get; set; }
}
```

todos esses modelos tem relação de coleção com o modelo `EmployeeSkillProject` com o seguinte modelo exemplo:

```
public partial class EmployeeSkillProject
{
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public int SkillId { get; set; }
  public int ProjectId { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
  public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
  public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
}
```

e nesse modelo existe a agregação dos outros três modelos. Para configurar um Contexto com a configuração desse modelo acima:

```
public partial class Ex001Context : DbContext
{
  private const string ConnectionString = "String de conexão";
  public Ex001Context()
     :base(ConnectionString)
  {
     Database.SetInitializer<Ex001Context>(null);
     Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;         
     Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;         
  }
  public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<EmployeeSkillProject> EmployeeSkillProject { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Project> Project { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Skill> Skill { get; set; }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
     modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");
     modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>().ToTable("Skill");
     modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkillProject>().ToTable("EmployeeSkillProject");

     modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .Property(x => x.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false);

     modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkillProject>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.EmployeeId, e.SkillId, e.ProjectId });

     modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkillProject>()
        .Property(x => x.Description)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false);

     modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkillProject>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Employee)
        .WithMany(p => p.EmployeeSkillProject)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.EmployeeId);

     modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkillProject>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Project)
        .WithMany(p => p.EmployeeSkillProject)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProjectId);

     modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkillProject>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Skill)
        .WithMany(p => p.EmployeeSkillProject)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.SkillId);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
        .Property(x => x.Description)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>()
        .Property(x => x.Title)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false);
  }
}
```

e na utilização básica por exemplo de adicionar:

```
using (Ex001Context db = new Ex001Context())
{
   Employee employee = new Employee();
   employee.Name = "Employee 2";

   Skill skill = new Skill();
   skill.Title = "Skill 2";

   Project project = new Project();
   project.Description = "Project 2";

   EmployeeSkillProject employeeSkillProject = new EmployeeSkillProject();

   employeeSkillProject.Employee = employee;
   employeeSkillProject.Skill = skill;
   employeeSkillProject.Project = project;
   employeeSkillProject.Description = "Employee, Skill, Project 2";

   db.Employee.Add(employee);
   db.Skill.Add(skill);
   db.Project.Add(project);
   db.EmployeeSkillProject.Add(employeeSkillProject);

   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Dessa forma tem um modelo prático, de fácil entendimento e que pode crescer com outros tipos de relações, e é de fato bom ratificar que a partir do momento que seu modelo sai do padrão do `ORM` no muitos para muitos, no caso citado é bom fazer a entidade que controla essas relações.